# Issue in getting param from Jenkins to Maven runtime

Tags: jenkins-plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using Maven surefire plugin to pass run-time parameters to Java run-time test environment. At java code level we're using

```
String buildId = System.getProperty("bsIosBuildId");
```

to accept the value in the code.

**Maven pom.xml snippet:**

https://gist.github.com/laxmikantm/30e77624e579351241b161220a5d0eaa

I have tried various combinations of bsIosBuildId but its not accepting a value from Jenkins.
Whereas below mvn command runs all fine from commandline.

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @test" -DtargetEnv="browserStackEnv" -DbsIosBuildId="blaBla"
```

**Snapshot from Jenkins job**
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix is sending the parameters to Maven as command line parameters.

This is how I implemented this.
[Jenkins Build Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7fvp.jpg)

For me the given Plug-Ins for Jenkins didn't work as they should.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is it possible to pass maven command line parameter through Jenkins? As only way I could run this set-up in production is through Jenkins

Comment: Yes, if you see the screen shot I embedded you will see how to send parameters. https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7fvp.jpg